# Incluir un enlace o como fichero de emails en un Sistema

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, email

Tengo un cliente al que estoy desarrollando un sistema de gestión de su empresa. En ese sistema hay mucha interacción con otras compañías para solucionar expedientes.

Muchas de esas interacciones son emails enviados por el propio sistema que ya me encargaré de guardar y visualizar en el sistema. Sin embargo, el cliente quiere de alguna forma guardar las respuestas a esos emails en el propio expediente en el sistema para tener toda la información centralizada.

No tendría que ser de forma automática (vamos que no tiene que conectarse al email obtenerlos y regitrarlos en el sistema, ya que no siguen un patrón definible), podría ser de alguna forma manual como guardando el email en un fichero y adjuntándolo al sistema o con algún tipo de link al correo, que al pincharlo se pudiera visualizar (aunque sea en la propia aplicación de correo).

He estado buscando por google pero no termino de verlo. ¿Alguien ha hecho algo parecido o me podéis orientar cómo hacerlo?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. No es un servidor propio de correo. De todas formas, como decía en la pregunta, no puedo automatizar la recepción de los correos, ya que muchas veces las respuestas no siguen una lógica o una referencia al mail enviado. Tendría que ser algo manual hecho por el propio usuario, que fuera el que adjuntara el mail al expediente concreto

Comment: Poder guardar un _link_ al correo va a depender de si la aplicación que utilizan de cliente de correo tiene la capacidad de gestionar esos links y que el correo esté disponible para todos los usuarios del sistema con el mismo vínculo (cosa poco probable). Algo que puede funcionarte es guardar dentro del sistema un archivo que contenga el correo. Por ejemplo, muchas aplicaciones tienen un formato propio (las de Microsoft lo hacen en archivos con extensión .eml).

Comment: Una solución simple y económica es que cuando un usuario quiera ver el correo, lo pones en un archivo temporal e invocas al shell para que lo vea con su aplicación de correo predeterminada –si tu aplicación es de escritorio–, o bien le entregas el archivo para que lo descargue a su sistema local y haga lo mismo. Una solución más integral, pero probablemente más cara, es crear tu o soportar un formato de archivo de correo y hacer directamente la visualización de su contenido.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta y perdón por la tardanza. Si, realmente vi que una posible solución es guardar el email ya sea en formato eml o msg y que al pulsar en él abra el cliente de correo correspondiente.